# Optimization of transfer matrix method for quarter wave stack

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, optimization

Does anyone have any tips for Matlab optimization algorithms to use with a 2x2 Transfer Matrix Method Program?

I have written a Matlab function that takes a series of refractive index values and evaluates the reflectance from the stack.

I'm designing a graded index coating and need to find a sequence of 5 refractive indices that give me the lowest possible reflectance. I have done this manually by changing the values of the row vector but would like to employ some kind of optimization to automate the process.

Comment: If written a multilayer coating optimiser in Python. The transfer matrix approach is used to calculate the reflectivity. I the couple this with a differential evolution or genetic algorithm codes which find the optimum configuration.